# How to display an image using service in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-service, android-imageview, android-file

I want to show image. where I have to perform operations in service and display result in UI. I don't want to use async task as per requirment. I don't know how to proceed and display image. Please help me.

My code has follows:

```
 public class Service_Photo extends Service {

        public Service_Photo() {

        }

        @Override

        public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {

            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");

        }

        @Override

        public void onCreate() {
            super.onCreate();    
            Toast.makeText(this, "The new Service was Created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }

        @Override

        public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {

            // For time consuming an long tasks you can launch a new thread here...

            Toast.makeText(this, " Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            updateImages();

        }
        private void updateImages()
        {
            String baseDir =  Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
            String fileName = "am/a.jpg";
            File f = new File(baseDir + File.separator + fileName);
            if(f.exists()){

                Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.getAbsolutePath());
            //     img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);
            // img.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Hello"+myBitmap.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();

            }
        }



        @Override

        public void onDestroy() {

            Toast.makeText(this, "Service Destroyed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }

       public class ImageDisplay extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
            //how to display the operation performed in service and display in image from service?
    }
    }
```

Comment: startActivity() that will show your image

Comment: sorry can't get you.how can i display in imageview? where to declare and get it? @pskink

Comment: Check how to update main thread from service it will resolve your problem I guess.

Comment: @Shadow create an Activity which has an ImageView in its UI and call setImageBitmap()

Comment: no that means it becomes straight forward by using in activity and no use of service. @pskink i want to use from service.

Comment: @Shadow call startActivity from your Service

Answer (score 0):

The best solution in your case is to use broadcast receivers. So in your activity

```
 BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver(onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
    if(intent.getAction().equals("your_load_photo_action"))
    {
           ImageDisplay.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                view.setImageBitmap("YourImage");
            }
            });
    }
    });

    @Override
    public void onResume()
    {
     LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mReceiver,
          new IntentFilter("your_load_photo_action"));
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause()
    {
     LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
    }
```

and on your `onCreate()` initialize your view

And in your service, in `updateImages()`
Just send broadcast an intent with the action "your_load_photo_action"

Comment: inside the method intent.getAction() i want to pass imageview id alone is enough? @Ahmed Hafez or where can i use setImageBitmap(Bitmap)?

Comment: Check my edits, you will define your view in your onCreate and then you will load your bitmap after receiving the intent